# how do I resolve this code error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: simrskhanza/frmUtama

Tags: java

how to solve this error, in the library section and others it is correct, maybe someone can solve this problem tsimrskhanza.SIMRSKhanza.lambda$main$0(SIMRSKhanza.java:23) and others

If I execute the program it will produce the same results

[image]

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   simrskhanza/frmUtama at
>   simrskhanza.SIMRSKhanza.lambda$main$0(SIMRSKhanza.java:23) at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   atjava.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>   atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>   atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simrskhanza.frmUtama at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: Instead of adding code as image, post your code into question. It will be easy to give answer.

Comment: My guess is incorrect CLASSPATH in your "run configuration". Have you seen [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html#deploy-classpath) page?